# I need help about strange files, I want to get data from these files with php (or suggest) and send it to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Here are the files:

1) In this [**website**](http://www.filedropper.com/all):this has excel file, sized 4kb only, that I can't edit, and when I try to get data from it with php, it says that this file is "read only" when it's not. This is price list from accounting program.

2)In this **[website](http://www.filedropper.com/file_31)**: is where the program saves the data I think so, but it's coded.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please have a look at this : http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php

Comment: So what is your actual problem? How are you trying to get data from the file with PHP? What Excel reader library are you using? If all you're trying to do is read data, why should it matter if it's a read-only file?

Comment: What operating system are you using? How does the "read only" message manifest - is it a PHP warning, or an error from a library?

Answer (score 0):

i try with all php excel reader i found in net :) i am using win 7, working with xampp in local.

problem is that, i think, that excell file is protected or something, it is exported from program.

i need to get data from that excell file or from another . rea file, they consists data about products : quantity, price, name and so, i can manually add all products to the site, but its better to get data from that program and automaticaly do it, and when there are changes in program it reflects on the site automaticaly, thx for the answers